# How to reload fetched data from server when page loads (created) in Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

When the page loads, some data is fetched from the server and is being displayed on this table

```
                            <tr v-for="option in options">
                                <td>
                                    <img :src="'/uploads/'+option.logo" class="img-thumbnail" width="130" height="90" />
                                </td>
                                <td>{{option.description}}</td>
                                <td v-if="option.homologated== false">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="homologate(option.idOption)">Homologate</button>
                                </td>
                                <td v-else>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

And I'm using this code to fetch data

```
    var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            options:[]
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.list();
    },
    methods: {
        list: function () {
            axios.get('@Url.Action("GetOptions", new {id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] })')
            .then(response => {
                this.options = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Erro',
                    text: 'Error'
                })
            })
        },
        homologate: function (id) {

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.set('id', id);

             axios.post('@Url.Action("Homologate")', formData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(error => { });
            this.list();
        }
    },
})
```

The problem is that when I call the method this.list() to refresh my table, nothing happens, I need to hit F5 to reload. Could this be happening because there's no method watched or computed? I'm new to Vue.JS, I tried to insert the list() method on watch but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was where I was calling the list() method.

```
homologate: function (id) {

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.set('id', id);

         axios.post('@Url.Action("Homologate")', formData)
            .then(response => {
   //THIS IS WHERE I NEEDED TO CALL  this.list();
            })
            .catch(error => { });

    }
```